# Set the value after receive another response in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I've got a question.

I've got two components and the Service. In the first component I call the request to the server (using one of the Service function) in OnInit function to get some data and then I want to pass the data to other components as well.

If I set the data in other components in OnInit function like this.data = this.responsedata.data the result is undefined because the first (main) request with all needed data haven't finished yet.

What is the best approach to when after the I get the data from the backend I could send it to the rest of components?

Answer (score 0):

Can you wait to initialize the child component until the request is done? Use something like:

```
<component *ngIf="responseIsParsed()">
```

Where responseIsParsed is a method on your component that returns true iff the response is processed.

Comment: thats sounds like a solution unless one got only a few components - and I do :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If multiple components need the same property, you can expose the property in the service and have each of the components that need it get it with a getter.

I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-Service

```
// ...
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    movies: IMovie[];
    private moviesUrl = './api/movies/movies.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        // Get the data immediately when the service is constructed
        this.getMovies().subscribe(m => this.movies = m);
    }

    private getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
            .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then the components obtain it with a getter like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html'
})
export class MovieListComponent {
    get movies(): IMovie[] {
        return this.movieService.movies;
    }

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }
}
```

When the data is retrieved by the service asynchronously, Angular's change detection picks it up and re-executes the getter, thereby getting the retrieved data and displaying it in the component's template.